# TFS Team Notifications not working

Tags: tfs

User notifications are working properly and if I configure my own user notification it works. But team notifications from TFS are not working.

From my understanding with the first image configuration, when a build in the project fails the user that requested the build should receive a notification. 
Am I losing anything?

On the second image is my user configuration that works properly.

*Note: "Requested by" is when the users execute the build directly in TFS and "Requested for" is when the user do an action that triggers the build.*

1. Team notification settings
   [image: Team Notification settings]
2. User notification settings
   [image: Team Notification setting]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I figure out why is not working.

The problem is I was setting the notifications at project level, as you can see in the first screenshot of the post, it was set to Develop. So I found two solutions:

1- At projects page: https://MyTfsUrl.com/tfs/MyCollection/_projects You have to select a Team in your project, so then set the notifications and the members of that team will receive the notifications.
[image]
As you can see in the image, now is selected **Develop/DevOpsDev** that is a team and notifications set there are working.

2- Other solution I found, and finally is the one I am using, is to set the notification at collections level on https://MyTfsUrl.com/tfs/MyCollection/_admin/_notifications?tab=Subscriptions
[image]
As I want to set notifications for a build fail. I decided that is a good option to inform the user involved in a failed build of all the projects.

Answer (score 1):

Check whether you have correct Delivery settings:

[image]

Comment: I think you have a different version of VSTS, in my version you can see the deliver options in the first image

Comment: Do you use VSTS or on-premise TFS?

Comment: I use on-premise TFS

Comment: Which version of TFS are you using? I'll have a test on my side.

Comment: Microsoft Visual Studio Team Foundation Server Version 15.112.26307.0

Comment: Are you able to receive the notification if you select to delivery to `All team members`? It's suggested to upgrade your TFS 2017 to the latest edition Update 3 first.